# How do I create a list of objects that are connected to an Azure webapp within another list of objects connected to an Azure Webapp in .NET Maui?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, xamarin, maui

Sorry for the confusing title. I am not sure how to put exactly what I am looking for into words, but I will try my best. I am currently making an application that populates a map with user-inputted pins (Restroom.cs Models), with each pin having it's own list of user-inputted reviews. Everything is inputted through a WebAPI that accesses my Azure WebApp. The reviews and the pins are working completely fine - the issue is that the same reviews are displayed across every pin. I understand I need to isolate some sort of way of making sure each pin has its own "review list", but I'm not exactly sure how to do this or where to start, since I am very new in programming with Azure and WebAPIs. I presume I have to make an ObservableRangeCollection property in Restroom.cs to store reviews, but I'm unsure where to go from there, and I also worry that some things may need to be adjusted since the reviews are going to be displayed on another page that isn't the main page.

Restroom.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace Dook.Shared.Models
{
    public class Restroom
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Column("Address")]
        public string Address { get; set; }
        [Column("Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Column("Latitude")]
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        [Column("Longitude")]
        public double Longitude { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Review.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SQLite;

namespace Dook.Shared.Models
{
    public class Review
    {
        [SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
        [Column("Id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Column("Username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Column("Stars")]
        public double Stars { get; set; }
        [Column("Text")]
        public string Text { get; set; }
        //[Column("Tags")]
        //public string Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

RestroomController.cs

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/Restroom")]
    public class RestroomController : ControllerBase
    {
        public static List<Restroom> Restroom { get; } = new List<Restroom>();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Restroom> Get()
        {
            return Restroom;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Restroom Get(int id)
        {
            return Restroom.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        }

        [HttpGet("{restId}")]
        public IEnumerable<Restroom> GetList(int restId)
        {
            List<Restroom> RestroomWithID = new List<Restroom>();

            foreach (Restroom rest in Restroom)
            {
                if (rest.RestroomId == restId)
                    RestroomWithID.Add(rest);
            }

            return RestroomWithID;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Restroom value)
        {
            Restroom.Add(value);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Restroom value)
        {
            var restroom = Restroom.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (restroom == null)
                return;

            restroom = value;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var restroom = Restroom.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (restroom == null)
                return;

            Restroom.Remove(restroom);
        }
    }
}
```

ReviewController

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.WebAPI.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("api/Review")]
    public class ReviewController : ControllerBase
    {
        public static List<Review> ReviewList { get; } = new List<Review>();

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<Review> Get()
        {
            return ReviewList;
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public Review Get(int id, int x)
        {
            return ReviewList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
        }

        [HttpGet("{restId}")]
        public IEnumerable<Review> GetWithRestroomID(int restId)
        {
            List<Review> ReviewWithID = new List<Review>();

            foreach(Review rev in ReviewList)
            {
                if(rev.RestroomId == restId)
                    ReviewWithID.Add(rev);
            }

            return ReviewWithID;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody] Review value)
        {
            ReviewList.Add(value);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody] Review value)
        {
            var review = ReviewList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (review == null)
                return;

            review = value;
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
            var review = ReviewList.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == id);
            if (review == null)
                return;

            ReviewList.Remove(review);
        }
    }
}
```

InternetRestroomService.cs

```
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Dook.Services
{
    public static class InternetRestroomService
    {
        //static string Baseurl = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ?
        //                                    "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:5000";
        static string BaseUrl = "https://dookwebapp.azurewebsites.net/";
        static HttpClient client;

        static InternetRestroomService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl)
            };
        }

        static Random random = new Random();

        public static async Task AddPinAsync(string name, string address, string username, double latitude, double longitude)
        {
            //Check to see if ID is a duplicate
            int idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
            var randomRestroom = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");
            Debug.Write(randomRestroom);

            while (randomRestroom != "")
            {
                idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
                randomRestroom = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");
            }

            var restroom = new Restroom
            {
                Name = name,
                Address = address,
                Username = username,
                Latitude = latitude,
                Longitude = longitude,
                Id = idNum
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(restroom);
            var content =
                new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/Restroom", content);

            if(!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task RemovePinAsync(int id)
        {
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync($"api/Restroom/{id}");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Restroom>> GetPinAsync()
        {
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync("api/Restroom");
            var restrooms = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Restroom>>(json);
            return restrooms;
        }

        public static async Task<Restroom> GetSingularPinAsync(int id)
        {
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{id}");
            var restroom = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Restroom>(json);
            return restroom;
        }
    }
}
```

InternetReviewService.cs

```
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.Services
{
    public static class InternetReviewService
    {
        //static string Baseurl = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ?
        //                                    "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:5000";
        static string BaseUrl = "https://dookwebapp.azurewebsites.net/";
        static HttpClient client;

        static InternetReviewService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl)
            };
        }

        static Random random = new Random();

        public static async Task AddReviewAsync(string username, double stars, string text, int restroomid)
        {
            //Check to see if ID is a duplicate
            int idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
            var randomReview = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");

            while (randomReview != "")
            {
                idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
                randomReview = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");
            }

            var review = new Review()
            {
                Username = username,
                Stars = stars,
                Text = text,
                Id = idNum,
                RestroomId = restroomid 
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(review);
            var content =
                new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/Restroom", content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task RemoveReviewAsync(int id)
        {
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync($"api/Restroom/{id}");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Review>> GetReviewAsync(int restId)
        {
            //var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{restId}");
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom", restId);

            try
            {
                var reviews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Review>>(json);
                return reviews;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString);
            }

            var review2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Review>>(json);
            return review2;
        }
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
namespace Dook;
using Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps;
using Microsoft.Maui.Maps;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Map = Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Maps.Map;
using Dook.ViewModel;
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using Dook.Services;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;

public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MoveMapLocation();
        PopulateMapAsync();
    }

    private void GoToLocation_Button(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MoveMapLocation();
    }

    private async void RefreshButton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await PopulateMapAsync();
    }

    private async void OnMapClicked(object sender, MapClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        var vm = (InternetMainViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        if (vm.AddCommand.CanExecute(e.Location))
            await vm.AddCommand.ExecuteAsync(e.Location);
        await PopulateMapAsync();
    }

    private void MoveMapLocation()
    {
        MapSpan mapSpan = new MapSpan(InternetMainViewModel.GetLocation(), 0.01, 0.01);
        mainmap.MoveToRegion(mapSpan);
    }

    private async Task PopulateMapAsync()
    {
        var restroomList = await InternetRestroomService.GetPinAsync();
        foreach (var restroom in restroomList)
        {
            Pin pin = new Pin
            {
                Label = restroom.Name,
                Address = restroom.Address,
                Type = PinType.Generic,
                Location = new Location(restroom.Latitude, restroom.Longitude)
            };
            pin.MarkerClicked += async (s, args) =>
            {
                args.HideInfoWindow = true;

                var vm = (InternetMainViewModel)this.BindingContext;
                Debug.Write(restroom.Id);
                if (vm.SelectedCommand.CanExecute(restroom))
                    await vm.SelectedCommand.ExecuteAsync(restroom);

                //mainmap.Pins.Remove(pin);
                //if(vm.RemoveCommand.CanExecute(restroom))
                //    await vm.RemoveCommand.ExecuteAsync(restroom);
                //await PopulateMapAsync();
            };

            mainmap.Pins.Add(pin);
        }
    }
}
```

RestroomDetailPage.xaml.cs

```
using Dook.Services;
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using Dook.ViewModel;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Dook.View;

[QueryProperty(nameof(RestroomId), nameof(RestroomId))]
public partial class RestroomDetailPage : ContentPage
{
    public string RestroomId { get; set; }
    public Restroom restroom { get; set; }
    public RestroomDetailPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var vm = (InternetRestroomDetailViewModel)this.BindingContext;
        ToolbarItem item = new ToolbarItem
        {
            Text = "Add"
        };
        item.Clicked += async (s, args) =>
        {
            if (vm.AddCommand.CanExecute(restroom.Id.ToString()))
                await vm.AddCommand.ExecuteAsync(restroom.Id.ToString());
        };
        this.ToolbarItems.Add(item);

        ICommand refreshCommand = new Command(() =>
        {
            if (vm.RefreshCommand.CanExecute(restroom.Id.ToString()))
                vm.RefreshCommand.ExecuteAsync(restroom.Id.ToString());
            
        });
        ReviewList.RefreshCommand = refreshCommand;
    }

    protected override async void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        int.TryParse(RestroomId, out var result);

        restroom = await InternetRestroomService.GetSingularPinAsync(result);
        BindingContext = restroom;
    }

  //  private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
  //  {
        //await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
  //  }
}
```

InternetRestroomDetailViewModel.cs

```
using Dook.Shared.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using SQLite;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Dook.Services
{
    public static class InternetReviewService
    {
        //static string Baseurl = DeviceInfo.Platform == DevicePlatform.Android ?
        //                                    "http://10.0.2.2:5000" : "http://localhost:5000";
        static string BaseUrl = "https://dookwebapp.azurewebsites.net/";
        static HttpClient client;

        static InternetReviewService()
        {
            client = new HttpClient()
            {
                BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseUrl)
            };
        }

        static Random random = new Random();

        public static async Task AddReviewAsync(string username, double stars, string text, int restroomid)
        {
            //Check to see if ID is a duplicate
            int idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
            var randomReview = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");

            while (randomReview != "")
            {
                idNum = random.Next(0, 100000);
                randomReview = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{idNum}");
            }

            var review = new Review()
            {
                Username = username,
                Stars = stars,
                Text = text,
                Id = idNum,
                RestroomId = restroomid 
            };

            var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(review);
            var content =
                new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

            var response = await client.PostAsync("api/Restroom", content);

            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task RemoveReviewAsync(int id)
        {
            var response = await client.DeleteAsync($"api/Restroom/{id}");
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {

            }
        }

        public static async Task<IEnumerable<Review>> GetReviewAsync(int restId)
        {
            //var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{restId}");
            var json = await client.GetStringAsync($"api/Restroom/{restId}");
            var reviews = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Review>>(json);
            return reviews;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a database.  The pin is a table in the database which is also a class in the c# code.  Reviews is a different table/class.  Each Pin needs an ID (property/field) that gets joined with Review Table that contains the same ID.

Comment: I see. That makes sense. I went up to the point of making sure each review made in a pin has the same "PinID" as the pin (separate from the "ReviewID", but I'm unsure how to make the RestroomDetailPage listview only display reviews with the same "PinID". How would you go about this?

Comment: GetReviewAsync Should accept a PinID as a parameter and only retrieve   Reviews that match

Comment: Following line of code should be changed to only get review for an ID : var json = await client.GetStringAsync("api/Restroom");

Comment: I tried implementing these changes, but I can't seem to get the GetReviewAsync method down -- json always includes a Restroom object, not a list of Restroom objects. I also tried changing RestroomController and ReviewController to include a GetList method, but I'm not sure how to call it within the GetReviewAsync method. Also, I'm not sure if I should be calling api/Restroom within the InternetReviewService (it worked before with the reviews), so that might be an issue as well. The post has been updated to include all the changes I made.